# What could be the reason for dock icons to have disappeared?

Tags: macos, desktop, icon

So this has happened to me again, my icons from desktop and the icons on dock and launchpad have been disappeared. I'm guessing that the icon builder daemon has crashed.

What should i do to get back all the icons to back where it was?

[image]

Comment: Running out of disk space? Cache Issue?

Comment: @powtac I have over 150 Gigs of space left.

Comment: Reset your screen resolution by changing it and then changing it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a strange behavior which happens to many users. One way to fix that is to open a terminal and use the killall-command.

Because the launchpad is connected with the dock, you can just use the following command to get your icons back:

```
killall Dock
```

That should fix your dock and launchpad-problem. But I don't know if it will help for the missing Desktop-icons.